# Reusing Swing components which are time-consuming to initialize

Tags: java, swing, components, initialization, reusability

If I have a massive Swing component in my application which takes a long time to initialize, and want to display this component in different places in my GUI at the same time, how would I preferably do this?

The GUI user must be able to interact with the different copies of the component
(they could, for example, work as mirrors).

Let's assume that one might want to display copies of this component dynamically, depending on the input of the GUI user (that is, we do not want pre-loading of many copies of the same component).

Comment: Do you mean that they all show the same thing or are kind of independant? If they are mirrors, then you can have painting problems if the main component relies on things like focus.

Comment: @Christopher the copies don't necessarily have to act like mirrors, but if they did, it would be ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your components to access data in a model-view like fashion.  Each component would need to point to the same model that would server up the data and do the intensive task once rather than multiple times.

Also, initialization is slowing the GUI, then it sounds like you need a splash screen or a progress bar and the task moved off the EDT.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion =). This is probably how I would normally do it. However, the problem for me is that I am using a third party component which is rather large and would take a lot of time to rewrite

Answer (score 2):

Is there any way that you could pull the heavy-duty initialization code out, maybe into a '...Factory' class?

Comment: I am not quite sure how that would solve it. Could you please elaborate this?

Comment: Ah I see, it's a third-party component you can't modify the source code for.  I thought you were developing your own component and might be able to pull out at least some of the initialization code.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a one instance of the component (let's say HeavyComponent) and a custom class extending e.g. JPanel and referencing the component. Let's name it MyContainer. On paintComponent() of the MyContainer I would draw original component into a BufferedImage or use heavyComponentReference.paint(g).
Then on click by the MyContainer I would swap the component replacing the panel with real instance of HeavyComponent and placing in the old location of the HeavyComponent new instance of MyContainer.

Comment: I like how this actually answers the question =). Since one would have to intercept the click and pass it on to the "real" instance, maybe it is easier to switch at mouseover?

Comment: Why not? It also possible but every remove/add needs revalidte and repaint so it could be called often and can have performance issues.

Answer (score -1):

> display this component in different
>   places in my GUI at the same time ...
>   without having to create a new copy of
>   the same component ... user must be able to interact with the different copies

No way.

Comment: I have updated the question now =). However, the original question was actually possible to solve, but the solution might not have been a good idea.